# Isuue with getting the value of inputHidden from a4j:form by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, hidden-field, ajax4jsf

I have the following issue. I need to get the hidden value that is in a4j:form from javascript.

```
<a4j:form id="orderModalFormId">
    <h:form style="display:none;" prependId="false">
            <h:inputHidden id="maxVal" value="#{bean.maxVal}"/>
    </h:form>

    //...rest code where javascript is used

</a4j:form>
```

in javascript

```
...    
var maxValue =  jQuery('#orderModalFormId : maxVal').val();
...
```

The problem is that during javascript debugging maxValue remains still undefined.
I'm pritty new in javascript and jQuery.
Where is a trick?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Creating the HTML psychically is tricky, but you almost certainly want just a simple `id` selector:

```
var maxValue = jQuery('#maxVal').val();
```

---

From the edit, it seems like you need this:

```
var maxValue = jQuery('#orderModalFormId\\:maxVal');
```

You need to escape the `:` so that jQuery doesn't parse it as a pseudo-selector. You need to use an escaped backslash (`\\:`) so that Javascript doesn't interpret `\:` as an escaped colon.

[See jsFiddle for an example of an escaped colon in an `id` selector](http://jsfiddle.net/rPGq6/).

Comment: The generated HTML id is `orderModalFormId:maxVal`.

Comment: In this particular case, yes. But other ways may be more useful for the case you have for example the `"orderModalFormId:maxVal"` or alone `"maxVal"` in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `:` is an illegal character in CSS selectors and those spaces doesn't make it better.

Either use good ol' JS:

```
var value = document.getElementById("orderModalFormId:maxVal").value;
```

Or escape it by double backslash:

```
var value = jQuery("#orderModalFormId\\:maxVal").val();
```

Or use the jQuery attribute selector:

```
var value = jQuery("id=['orderModalFormId:maxVal']").val();
```

Or when the JS is embedded in a JSF page (and you're using RichFaces already):

```
var value = #{rich:component('maxVal')}.val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both of you were right about the syntax but the problem was of another nature.
It appeared that my ajax form didn't work with my javascript properly, so what i did was just pathing parameter of maxVal into this a4j:form by means of ui:include (my a4j:form is in separate xhtml file). Like this:

mainPage.xhtml

```
<h:form style="display:none;" prependId="false">
   <h:inputHidden id="maxVald" value="#{mainBean.maxVal}"/>
</h:form>

<ui:include src="/xhtml/include/orderModalForm.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="maxVal" value="#{mainBean.maxVal}"/>
</ui:include>
```

and in javascript i did like this

```
var maxFreezePeriod =  jQuery('#maxFreezePeriod').val();
```

Thanks for your answers :)